# REST API with the running Java project

Tags: java, rest, webapi

I have a Java project up and running.

`java -Xmx1g -cp $classpath $runnableclass -url $url $arguments`

This will printout the results in terminal.

I want to create a web API so that I can run this in a webpage. I want users to enter their URL and get the results on the webpage while the parameters set in the webpage using boxes or radio buttons. My search for such application didn't go any where since most of the examples were not showing how to use a package in REST API.

I'd appreciate if you can direct me to some templates or examples or tutorials.

Comment: Use Jersey and then deploy it in either servlet container or you can start it as small server

Comment: Is there any template for that?

Comment: I could run a local server api but how to push it to a remote host.

Comment: What do you mean by push it to remote host. Do you have some sample API. Use vogella blog and read jersey rest that should help

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mashape:

> Just by adding your API to mashape's marketplace you get instant exposure to our growing userbase and a search engine optimized profile page for your API. You get everything for free. We don't charge developers a dime unless they are utilizing our billing system and making money themselves.

http://docs.mashape.com/overview